# Unable to display data using datatables with source as Javascript

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery datatables to display data using Javascript as DataSource .

This is my complete program , when i ran the below program it shows an Empty table . 
could anybody please let me know how to resolve this ??

```
<html>
<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>

var dataddd = {

  "data": [
    {
      "first_name": "Airi",
      "last_name": "Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "start_date": "28th Nov 08",
      "salary": "$162,700"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Angelica",
      "last_name": "Ramos",
      "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "office": "London",
      "start_date": "9th Oct 09",
      "salary": "$1,200,000"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
     "aaData": dataddd,
            "columns": [
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write `dataddd.data` instead of `dataddd`.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
 "aaData": dataddd.data,
        "columns": [
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "last_name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ]
});
```